# How to make PageTabBarController scroll to side?

Tags: cosmicmind

I have a PageTabBarController with 8 itens, how to make the menu itens scroll horizontal to fit all itens ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That feature is being worked on. Shouldn't be much longer, but currently, it is not available. Here is the [PageTabBar Scrollable feature request](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material/issues/642) that you can follow.